# If I buy a vehicle online, and I don't have a garage, where does it go?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I really like this one specific bike, which is worth only 15k.  But, I don't have a garage.  If I purchase the bike online, where will the bike go? I don't have a house, either.

Comment: Uhm. You can't purchase a car / bike when you haven't a garage! The website say: "Purchase failed. You have no space to store" or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't buy a car if you do not own a garage to store it. The cheapest garage is a 2 car garage titled "Unit 124 Popular St." that will cost you $25000.

Just like in the real world, you can't just go leaving your cars all over town!

Comment: `Just like in the real world, you can't just go leaving your cars all over town!` Err... wat???   I think we live in different "real worlds".

Comment: I mean permanently. As in... If you just start leaving your cars places overnight in strange places they are likely to be towed or messed with.